# What is a "4P" Lens?

Tags: lens

I am a noob in photography and don't have any idea of lenses and optics...

Recently though I was looking out for some camera modules and couldn't understand some of the specifications mentioned in the data-sheet.

One of them stated that the Lens construction is 4P + IR, what does this mean?... To an extent I understand the IR part indicates to some filter in the lens.

I searched for the term "4P Lens" on the web but it didn't return relevant results either?

Comment: One answer appears in the first hit when you Google "4P + IR lens": "4P = four plastic lenses; 1G = one glass lens; IR = infrared filter"

Comment: @whuber: Thanks, so why exactly do we need these four plastic lenses or glass lenses? Is there some reference that explains the construction and understanding of lenses.

Comment: You might start at the Wikipedia article and then explore whatever interests you in the links from it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_lens

Comment: It might be useful to add a link to the data-sheet you mention

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about 4P, but at least in CCTV IR lenses are lenses that are corrected for [infrared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) wavelengths, which means you can use them with day/night cameras that switch to IR when it goes dark (see [Tamron site](http://www.tamron.com/en/cctv_ip/fixed/) for examples of these).

Comment: I may be wrong, but my thinking was that the IR part was a filter attached behind the lens and it was to remove the IR component of light entering the camera.

Comment: Tamron explanation at http://www.tamron.co.jp/en/data/cctv_ir/ir_series2.html suggest that at least for Tamron it works the way I described.

Comment: I think you're both correct: you need to remove the IR filter from the sensor in order to shoot IR, and having an IR-corrected lens helps with focusing.

Comment: Kevin's link actually says 4Plastic + IR; so I'd say you're spot on.

Answer (score 3):

I think f/4P should be read "f/4" + "P". f/4 is clear, "P" according to [this](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/nikortek.htm) documentation means:

> P lenses are manual focus AI-s lenses
>   that have had the electronic contacts
>   of an AF lens added to them.
>
> There are only a few of these: the
>   500mm f/4 P from 1988, the 1200 - 1700
>   mm f/5.6-8.0 P ED and the new 45mm
>   f/2.8 P.
>
> They allow Matrix metering and I
>   believe the addition of all the
>   automatic exposure modes on AF
>   cameras.
>
> Again, these are manual focus lenses
>   that are unique in their ability to
>   take advantage of exposure and
>   metering modes usually reserved only
>   for AF lenses on AF cameras. You still
>   have to focus them by hand.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now after reading this, whuber mentions that 4P means a 4 element plastic lens. The datasheet of this particular camera states that it is fixed focus, I don't know about manual focus adjustment and the electronic contacts of AF as said in your answer. What conclusions should I come to?

Comment: The naming is very confusing. The same letter has several meanings. Maybe if you show the full name, someone will give you a better answer.

Comment: This wasn't a question about Nikon lenses, I think.

Answer (score 1):

By the broken link you mention in your comment, it looks it's a specific naming for Truly company about the CCM (Compact Camera Module).
I would recommend to edit your question to be more specific about where your find those mentions as it does not look to be an official standard.
(And anyway each brands have their own nomenclature).

As the other answer mention Nikkor AI-P my answer will not mention this as it does not look related to the Nikon / Nikkor nomenclature.

I do not find the exact pdf specifications you mentionned but by looking to another similar document [here](http://www.trulyamerica.com/wp-content/uploads/CM6787-O500BA-E.pdf) they mentions: `1/4 inch 4Plastic+ IR` which looks like 4 plastic elements and IR filtering. What the specification does not mention is how the IR filtering is exactly done: a specific lens element or just a filter behind the lens.

But the 4P in that context means for sure `4Plastic` elements.